# Android Layout with ImageButton overlapping other elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, xamarin.android

I am trying to offset a button and have its location be so that it appears to hang over other elements.  What I am looking for can be seen in this image... notice the image button, which is id ibLoginButton in my xml, where the red arrow is pointing:

[image]

Here is the xml for my layout, but I do not know how to make ibLoginButton have that effect.  Do I need to do this programmatically? If so, how?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/TitleBar"
        android:layout_height="54dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLoginPicture"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/MDSLogoForLoginTrans"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoginName"
            android:text="Dr. Dentist"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="230.5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivLoginPicture"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibLogout"
            android:src="@drawable/logoutButton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/ibLoginButton"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/HomePage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/home_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/Grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradientNews"
        android:id="@+id/webView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone with knowledge of Android Layouts please shed some light!!! I am stumped.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple changes that need to be made

- Need to make the top `LinearLayout` into a `RelativeLayout`.
- Need to move the `ibLoginButton` button outside of its `RelativeLayout`
- `ibLoginButton` needs to be after both regions it overlays, since items at the bottom of `RelativeLayout`'s are drawn on the top.

Full example code that will give you what you want (looks good in Eclipse's Graphical Layout preview).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/TitleBar"
        android:id="@+id/first_relative"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="54dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLoginPicture"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/MDSLogoForLoginTrans"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibLogout"
            android:src="@drawable/logoutButton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoginName"
            android:layout_width="230.5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibLogout"
            android:text="Dr. Dentist"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/HomePage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/home_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_relative">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/Grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradientNews"
        android:id="@+id/webView1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibLoginButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As an aside, it should be possible to only use a single relative layout. Using the minimal number of containers is best practice for performance reasons.

Comment: I added the button as you described and made the other changes.  I understand what you did, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put betwen titlebar and homepage

```
<View android:layout_width="40dp" 
      android:layout_height="40dp" 
      layout_gravity="center_horizontally" 
      layout_margin_top="-20dp" background="ef0"/>
```

The idea here is negative margins

Comment: I don't think this works. The height of the button's container is 54dp. Regardless of your margins, the button isn't going to leave the parents 54dp region.

Answer (score 1):

Center horizontally and then adjust your margins. You know topbar's height, you can set a top margin of 44 - half of the image's height